# Error encoding categorical features using sklearn pipelines

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, pipelines

I am new to sklearn pipelines and am using this post as a guide for my code:

https://www.codementor.io/bruce3557/beautiful-machine-learning-pipeline-with-scikit-learn-uiqapbxuj

I am trying to encode a categorical features using a transformation pipeline, but no matter what encoder I use, I get the same error. As far as I can tell from reading other posts, scikit-learn should be able to handle categorical variables as strings from version 0.20 or greater (namely with the OneHotEncoder.)

```py
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Male'
```

Where I have entered xxxxxxxxxxx below replace with one of the following

```py
ce.OneHotEncoder
ce.TargetEncoder
OneHotEncoder
OrdinalEncoder
```

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import Imputer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.decomposition import NMF
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
import category_encoders as ce
from sklearn.preprocessing import OrdinalEncoder
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create example data
example_df = pd.DataFrame({'Sex':['Male','Female','Female'],'Survived':[1,1,0]})
X_train = example_df.drop('Survived', axis=1)
y_train = pd.DataFrame(example_df['Survived'])

# build example pipeline
cat_pipe = ("categorical_features", ColumnTransformer([
            ("categorical", Pipeline(steps=[
                ("impute_stage", Imputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy="median")),
                ("label_encoder", xxxxxxxxxxx())]), ["Sex"]
            )])
          )

example_pipeline = Pipeline(steps=[cat_pipe])

# fit pipeline
example_pipeline.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```py
# Name                    Version 
scikit-learn              0.20.3 
category_encoders         1.3.0
numpy                     1.16.2
pandas                    0.24.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line:

```
("impute_stage", Imputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy="median"))
```

Because your input type is string, you shouldn't fill the null value to `median` (we cannot average string value).

From the [document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.impute.SimpleImputer.html), you can fill null value with a string constant like:

```
Imputer(missing_values=None, strategy="constant", fill_value="NULL")
```

to represent null value in your string field.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I thought I had put mode - turns out you should use "most frequent." My code now reads as follows: 

```
("impute_stage", Imputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy="most_frequent"))

```

However I am still getting the same error as in the original post. Oddly when I implement strategy="constant" and fill_value="NULL" I get the following error: 
```
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'fill_value'
```

Comment: Oh sorry, please check whether your null value type is `None`. If so, we should change the imputer to `Imputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy="constant", fill_value="NULL")`

Comment: I do agree that the problem is somewhere with the imputer - as if I remove it the encoder works as expected. It turns out that if I replace Imputer with SimpleImputer the pipeline works as expected! Thanks for getting me in the right direction.